# jqGrid Edit Form Dialog Modal Background Moves Rest Of The Page

Tags: css, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

I am using jqGrid 1.7.3. For manipulating rows I use jqGrid's form editing capabilities (modal dialog). Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but if it comes to Internet Explorer ... well what shall I say.

Actually the edit window shows up fine but the background behind the dialog is not positioned over the rest of the page but moves eveything down!

i actually changed the css for that but nothing happens. So it seems the background gets its css info by jqgrid and not by any css decleration.

has anybody a clue how to set the css right ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you have resolved this yet, but I'd recommend checking the rendering mode of the browser to see whether it's rendering HTML in 'quirks' mode. I had the same issue and it turned out that my DOCTYPE declaration was wrong causing internet explorer to adopt the 'quirks' mode of rendering.

There are probably easier ways to do this, but I determined the rendering mode by loading the page using the program IETester with the DebugBar toolbar installed. Then by looking at the info tab on DebugBar, the rendering mode is specified.

Once I confirmed it was running in quirks mode, I looked at different DOCTYPE declaration options. Once I set the DOCTYPE to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

the page loaded fine and the JQgrid form editing dialog also worked fine. The rendering mode as specified in IETester showed 'standards mode IE8'.